# How do I install Ubuntu on to a second Hard Drive?

Tags: system-installation

I have 2 HDD in my computer at the moment... One 2TB HDD that is running Windows 8 and one 1TB HDD that I would like to install Ubuntu on. I bought the second HDD so that the two don't have to conflict with each other at all!

How do I install Ubuntu onto my second HDD, without affecting my first, and then when I boot up my computer, how can I choose between which OS to use? I have seen it at a friends house: they have a black screen on startup which they can then choose whether they want Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Boot up your Ubuntu install media and choose instal Ubuntu. When it gets to the Install Along Side Windows options screen, pick the one at the buttom saying something like "Something Else". This will get you to the partitioner, where you can select the drives and installs as you want. Select your 1 TB drive (probably called /dev/sdb and format it so it uses the ext4 file system. This will make Ubuntu get on the 1 TB drive without touching the 2 TB drive. 
After this it gets tricky.
The black screen you refer to is the Windows Boot Manager. I don't know how to get that to show up instead of Grub.

If you want Grub Bootloader instead, always install it on the first drive (usually /dev/sda).